# laravel, How to check if this is the last record

Tags: php, laravel

how can I check if the current record is the last one in the model?

```
   $lastorder=Order::find($order_id);
    if($lastorder->last())
```

Comment: Something like `Order::latest()->first()->id == Order::find($order_id)->id`

Comment: This does not make much sense to me find will always work from id, which usually is primary which means it's unique. The order you retrieved is the only one, thus making it first and last.
Please adjust the sample if you are actually querying for multiple records with get/all.
To get last order alongside you need to make 2nd query over to Order model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$orders = Order::where('id','>=', $order_id)->get();

$order = $orders->first();

if($orders->count() > 1) {
   //...
   // NOT the last record :(
   //...
} else { 
   //...
   // Last record :)
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it all in one round trip to the database!

In MySQL you'd write:

```
SELECT *
FROM oders
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM orders) AND id = [$order_id]
```

So in Eloquent you'd write something like:

```
Order::where('id', $order_id)
     ->where('id', function($q) {
         $query->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
               ->from('orders');
     })->first();
```

Check if that is `null` and you'll know!

Answer (score 0):

```
$order=Order::find($order_id);
$last_record = Order::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
if($order->id == $last_record->id)
{
    //last record;
}
```

Assuming that Order table contains id as primary key.